# qabstractitemmodel How to refer sublist to model

Tags: qt, qml, qabstractitemmodel, qabstractlistmodel

Hi I have an virtual data metod of qabstractitemmodel  like :

```
 m_roleNames.insert(FirstNameRole, QByteArray("firstName"));
  m_roleNames.insert(LastNameRole, QByteArray("lastName"));
  m_roleNames.insert(SubListRole, QByteArray("subList"));   

QVariant SimpleListModel::data(const QModelIndex &index,
                                            int role) const {
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant(); // Return Null variant if index is invalid
    if (index.row() > (m_items.size()-1) )
        return QVariant();

    DataObject *dobj = m_items.at(index.row());
    switch (role) {
    case Qt::DisplayRole: // The default display role now displays the first name as well
    case FirstNameRole:
        return QVariant::fromValue(dobj->first);
    case LastNameRole:
        return QVariant::fromValue(dobj->last);
    case SubListRole:
        return QVariant::fromValue(dobj->sublist);
    default:
        return QVariant();
     }
    }
```

I can refer firstName to listview.It is OK.But ı want to use list type like sublist[0].member.I can't refer it to listview.

```
  ....
   ...
   ..
   .
    text: firstName
          color: "black"
          font.bold: true
                           }
                       Text {
text: subList[1]
          color: "black"
                       }
                   }
           }
        }
        }
    .
    ..
    ...
    ....
```

**EDIT**
I have added Sublist classes: `    class SubObject :public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        SubObject(const QString &lesson,QObject *parent = 0):
            QObject(parent),
            lesson(lesson)
        {}

```
     const QString lesson;

private:


//    bool operator==(const SubObject*  &other) const {
//           return other->lesson == lesson;
//    }

};

class DataObject :public QObject{

    Q_OBJECT

public:
  DataObject(const QString &firstName,
             const QString &lastName,
             const QList<SubObject*>   &sublist):
     first(firstName),
     last(lastName),
    sublist(sublist){}
  QString first;
  QString last;
  QList<SubObject*> sublist;
};

#endif // DATAOBJECT_H`
```

Comment: Please improve this question. It is not clear what is going on here. Trying to answer to your problem: If you want to use a C++ class by calling its members in QML try using `Q_PROPERTY`. More info [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html).

Comment: @FilipHazubski , I don't want to use Q_PROPERTY system.I want to use qabstractitemmodel type.I use data virtual metod and roleNames . If data returns single type . it can be refer.But it returns QList<T> , ı can't refer sub members.

Comment: You can make a `QList` of an `QObject` with `Q_PROPERTY` and use `QQmlListProperty` to expose this `QList` to QML. Have a look [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-referenceexamples-properties-example.html).

Comment: @FilipHazubski `QQmlListProperty` is meant to be  used as a declarative list where you define the list from QML. Like `states` in `Item`.
If you just want to expose a list, use a `QList<QObject*>` if it is static,  or a  `QAbstractListModel` otherwise.

Comment: @Kevinyudo what's the type of `dobj->sublist` ?

Comment: @GrecKo Interesting. I have some more questions and I would appreciate your help. If you want you will find me in [this chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113392).

Comment: @GrecKo dobj->sublist is QList<Sublist*>. Sublist has an member which name is lesson.I want to make refer sublist[0].lesson.

Comment: @FilipHazubski , Can you give me some example I don't unserstand using QQmlListProperty with QAbstractList model

Comment: I usually do not use `QAbstractListModel` but I use `QQmlListProperty`. You can read about it [here, section Properties with Object-List Types](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html). Please also have a look [here](http://gitlab.unique-conception.org/qt-qml-tricks/qt-qml-models), maybe it will be useful to you.

Comment: @FilipHazubski , My wish is simple.I can refer first and last to listview OK.But I want to refer sublist[0].lesson is not success.How to return a list from virtual  data metod of  QAbstractListModel